# Vercel Deployment only showing index.js instead of application

Tags: react-native, vercel

After deploying app on vercel using the vercel command

Only this Shows up

import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);

im using node 18, tried node 16 but still the same results, please help, is it a bug or am i doing something wrong

im using node 18, tried node 16 but still the same results, please help, is it a bug or am i doing something wrong